group by and sum in DAX based on the fiscal week
I have a data as below and I would like to create a powerbi card to show the current Fiscal week and the previous fiscal week value. many thanks in advance.
Expected Answer :
Current Amt: 20
Previous Amt: 35

Current input :
FiscalWeek  Group   Amt FiscalYear
52          gorup1  10  FY23
52          gorup2  20  FY24
51          gorup1  30  FY24
51          gorup2  5   FY24
50          gorup1  10  FY24
50          gorup2  15  FY24


You need 2 measures for current and previous :
Current Amt = 
VAR CurrentFiscalWeek = MAX('TableTest'[FiscalWeek])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM('TableTest'[Amt]),
    'TableTest'[FiscalWeek] = CurrentFiscalWeek
)

Previous Amt = 
VAR CurrentFiscalWeek = MAX('TableTest'[FiscalWeek])
VAR PreviousFiscalWeek = CurrentFiscalWeek - 1
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM('TableTest'[Amt]),
    'TableTest'[FiscalWeek] = PreviousFiscalWeek
)

You can use the new card visual :



